# How do you share a detached expo project?

Tags: expo

Once you detach from expo you have an `EXShell.plist` file that is needed to build the project, but it appears to need different data for anyone that works on the project.  In particular the `manifestUrl`  Is it possible to keep this file in the git repo without breaking the build of everyone other than the last committer?